# iOS display a lock/unlock slider like the lock screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, slider

I'm trying to let the users of my app cancel an active alarm using a slider, like the timer app or the iPhone lock screen.

Is this control available to us as developers? If so, what's the name of it, and do I need to add it programmatically? I do not see it in the interface builder.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you, but did you manage to get your app on the App Store? Didn't you run into troubles because the slider was just like Apple's?

Comment: I would like to know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go,
http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-do-slide-to-unlock.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Answer (score 8):

You could always try this on cocoacontrols.

[Slide to unlock control](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/slide-to-unlock)

Comment: Not sure why I got -1 for offering a link to a control that is exactly what was asked for.

Comment: I don't either. +1 for you. :)

Comment: You got -1 because you wrote a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard control - you'll need to create it yourself.

However, I think you should be able to customize the slider control.  You can change the look and feel of that by supplying your own graphics, and it should be easy to simulate the behavior of the lock slider (such as making it slide back to 0 if it doesn't get all the way across).